# Insert EXPLICITLY STATED values on some condition from another table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I spent some time looking but cannot find one answer that satisfies what I am trying to accomplish.

I want to insert some explicitly stated values into `table1` based on some condition in `table2`

The logic goes as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2, col3)
VALUES(value1, value2, value3)
ONLY IF (SELECT attribute from table2 WHERE id=1) NOT LIKE 'A')
```

I NEED to explicitly insert the values and not `INSERT SELECT` from other table. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What do you mean by "attribute1 NOT LIKE 'A' in table 2"? There is no such thing. "attribute1 NOT LIKE 'A'" may be true or false, independently in each row of a table - what do you mean by **in table 2**? Then, your concern about INSERT SELECT makes no sense either. If you must insert hard-coded values, you SELECT them from DUAL, and you add whatever conditions you need there.

Comment: you would have to use pl sql for it

Comment: @nikhilsugandh - let me point out that by the time you posted your nonsensical comment, I had already shown how to do it in plain SQL.

Comment: @mathguy what is non sensical there may i know???

Comment: @nikhilsugandh - the comment that "you have to use PL SQL" after I had already shown, in my answer, that that's not the case. Not the same if my answer hadn't been there already.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited** following clarification from OP.

```
insert into table1(col1, col2, col3)
  select value1, value2, value3
  from   dual
  where  (select attribute from table2 where id = 1) != 'A';
```

This assumes that `table1` has exactly one row where `id = 1`, and the `attribute` is not `null`. For a slightly more general case, where there may be no row with `id = 1`, or there is one such row but the attribute can be `null`, you can write the `where` condition like so:

```
where nvl( (select attribute from table2 where id = 1), 'B' ) != 'A'
```

Comment: I see that someone downvoted the answer, within 45 seconds of it being posted. That demonstrates unbelievable reading skills. An explanation may be helpful.

Comment: At least, you're now *even*.

Comment: Take +1 more from me!

Comment: @Littlefoot - I don't care about "even", or "downvote", or "reputation" - it just bothers me that people will downvote without explaining what they found wrong with the answer. Pretty lame, that - I don't get a chance to defend my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's how it goes. As long as upvotes are self-explanatory, downvotes sometimes aren't. True, there are obvious ones, but in cases as yours, I have a feeling that downvoting should be *moderated*, i.e. you should *explain* why you downvoted, and that shouldn't be "blajsflai" but something that actually means something. As that probably means that moderator (?) should approve it, I have yet another feeling that it won't happen. So, here we are - downvoted without an obvious reason (though, *mean* as I am, I don't have too many doubts).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry I wasn't articulating it clearly and I made some amendment to the code.

What I really want to do is to insert certain values when some condition in another table is present. 

The actual use case is something similar to ' insert 1000 dollars into money(in the money table) if the name attribute in bank account (in a bank account table) has name 'Jesus''.

I understand it might be a really simple operation to some of the more experienced but I am very new to SQL. Really appreciate the responses from all of you.

Comment: @VincentLam - the query can then be written very similarly to what I posted. I can amend my answer, but first please address my last question: why `LIKE 'A'` and not `= 'A'`?

Comment: @mathguy I thought that was how string comparison is done in SQL. It is pure ignorance and complacency of the language on my part.